# Tomcat what is Thread Total Started Count

Tags: linux, multithreading, tomcat, jvm

We are monitoring Tomcat using SNMP tool and its showing me.

Thread Total Started Count = 500 (It's changing frequently)

I have hunt down OID and i found its "jvmThreadTotalStartedCount" http://support.ipmonitor.com/mibs/JVM-MANAGEMENT-MIB/item.aspx?id=jvmThreadTotalStartedCount

It is saying: The total number of threads created and started since the Java Virtual Machine started.

My question is what this means? Could someone explain me in simple/basic language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) is a flow of execution within a [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). There are processes that only have a single flow of execution (single-threaded) and others, like Tomcat, which partition their behavior into several flows of execution, in parallel (multi-threaded).

Tomcat, as a web server, typically allocates one thread to handle each request it receives, up to a limit (might be `500` in your case), after which following requests are queued, waiting for a thread to become free to handle them. This is known as [thread pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pooling).

So, to answer your first question, `Thread Total Started Count` is the total count of all the different flows of execution that have been created by this instance of Tomcat since it started running.

Comment: Thanks for reply, But its up/down very frequently. yesterday it was around 6000... and my tomcat was very slow.

Comment: Does it means total thread created by all pool in code base, even though they were destroyed in future. Or it is total number of runable/callable executed so far.